# Integrating minimum of density $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \min [\pi(x), \pi(y) ]q(x,y) dxdy$

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution

I am having trouble evaluating the following double integral. Let

$$\pi(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$$ be the density of a standard normal and
$$q(x,y)= \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{y-x}{\sigma}\right)^2} $$another normal density. Show that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \min\{\pi(x), \pi(y) \} q(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan\left(\frac{2}{\sigma}\right)$$

any ideas?

Comment: Divide into two parts $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \pi(y)\int_{-y}^yq(x,y)dxdy+\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{|x|\gt|y|}\pi(x)q(x,y)dxdy$  Suggestion don't use $\pi $ as a function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines $y=\pm x$ partitions the whole domain into 4 subdomains and the 4 sub-integrals are the same in value

\begin{align}
I=4\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{-x}^x \pi(x) q(x,y)\> dy  dx \\
\end{align}
Integrate in polar coordinates

\begin{align}
I
=&\>4\int_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi4} \int_{0}^\infty \frac1{2\pi\sigma} e^{-\frac12r^2 \cos^2t-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}(\sin t-\cos t)^2} r\>dr  \, dt \\
=& \frac2{\pi\sigma} \int_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi4}
\frac1{ \cos^2t+\frac1{\sigma^2}(\sin t-\cos t)^2} dt\\
 =& \frac{2\sigma}{\pi} \int_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi4}
\frac{\sec^2t}{ \sigma^2+(\tan t-1)^2} dt
=\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan \frac{2}{\sigma}
\end{align}